# Showing Android keyboard when activity/fragment first appears

Tags: android, keyboard

It seems like in recent versions of Android, focusing an input automatically shows the soft keyboard (which is what I'd like to happen). But when an Activity/Fragment first appears, if an input is already focused, the keyboard isn't onscreen. I've gone through a bunch of SO posts that seem to provide solutions, but I can get none of them to work.

This feels like one of those one-liners that I just haven't managed to dig up...what's the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I just gave up and do  :

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    imm.showSoftInput(textView,
                                            InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                                    textView.selectAll();
                                }
                            }, 200);
```